Androidx custom preference example (like NumberPickerPreference)
For years I have been using custom preferences like a NumberPickerPreference or ColorPickerPreference. The old PreferenceScreen has been deprecated by API 29. The AndroidX Preference Library is the way to go to get consistent behavior across all devices.
Do you have an example of a Custom preference in Java that fits in the AndroidX PreferenceScreen? For example a ColorPickerPreference or a NumberPickerPreference?
I scanned the internet for examples for quite some time and could not find a good example yet.

What is "The old Preference setup" and how is it deprecated? What do you mean by "that fits in the AndroidX PreferenceScreen"? That fits how? What doesn't "fit" now?

Finally found a few working Custom Preferences!

NumberPickerPreference;
ColorPickerPreference.

